# How to make a table only one line high using html/css?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to find a simple way to create a 1 row, 3 column table using css. I want the table width to be the width of the container div, and the height to be just 1 line. The first and third column should expand to contain the width of the text. The middle column should fill any remaining width (up to the container width), with overflow hidden.

I am having trouble with the middle column. When I use white-space:nowrap and overflow:hidden it extends the table beyond the width of the container div.

```
<div style="width:500px;">
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
            Title is Here
        </td>
        <td style="">
            When this is too long to display on one line the overflow is hidden
        </td>
        <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
            Last updated 12:05pm
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

or is there maybe an easier way using div? but I can't seen to figure out how to make the center div only fill the space available instead of moving to the next line.

```
<div style="width:500px;">
    <div style="float:left;">
        Title is Here
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;">
        When this is too long to display on one line the overflow is hidden
    </div>
    <div style="float:right;">
        Last updated 12:05pm
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is using table necessary?

Comment: "sounds like" span to me :)

Answer (score 2):

[you could do it with div based layout too](http://jsfiddle.net/vvmH3/)

### css

```
     .table{width: 100%; }
     .table, .table .item{ height: 20px; overflow: hidden;}
     .table .item{float: left; box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; background: #fcc; text-align: center;}
     .table .item.right{float: right;}
     .table .center{float: none; background: #ccf; }
```

### markup

```
  <div class="table">
     <div class="item left">left content</div>
     <div class="item right">right content</div>
     <div class="center item">some center content</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is excellent. Thanks for the example. Will this be ok on older versions of IE as well? I can only check IE8 and Firefox at the moment.

Comment: it works in IE 7/8/9, Firefox, and Google chrome for me :) This technique doesn't use _tricky_ css or vendor specific style, so I believe it'll work fine in all browses (it doesn't _base_ on _box-sizing_ CSS property so removing it will keep the layout intact)

Answer (score 0):

your middle td doesn't have any `width` or `height` specified. Therefore,  it has default `width:auto` and `height:auto`. That's why, it always scales itself up. If you try to give your td a fixed `width`, it will scale vertically.
You can stop this by giving it a fixed `height` and `width` along with `display:inline-block;`

same goes for divs also. but in case of divs, you don't need to specify display:inline-block;

you need to give your td (first sample ) or div(second sample) a fixed width and height, to hide the overflow i.e. to make `overflow:hidden;` work.

**table based layout:**

try this css in your middle `td` : see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CVmqN/1/)

```
.middle
{
    height:20px;
    width:70%;
    overflow:hidden; 
    display:inline-block; /*add this property also for the td */
}
```

**div based layout**

give your div this css: see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3zq37/)

```
.middle
{
    float:left;
    width:40%; 
    height:20px; 
    overflow:hidden;
}
```